# Как в js перейти по ссылке со своим протоколом?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Зарегистрировал свой протокол в системе: "sdp://" Подскажите пожалуйста как в js перейти по ссылке такого вида: "sdp://qweasd"?

Comment: window.location = "sdp://qweasd"

Comment: @Даниил Не получается, даже со стандартным ya.ru ```<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).location = "ya.ru";
    });
</script>```

Comment: window.location = "//qweasd"